# Secure api keys with jwt without authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

Is there any ways to secure the api response with jwt or any other method but without authentication (login page) so that only owner site can have access to the api. 
All the methods and tutorials I saw on google was based on login system with jwt.

As an example, if I have rest api like:

```
router.get('/api/posts', (req, res) => {
 var body = ... // get some via database
 res.json(body);
})
```

Then I want to consume this only by my site: `example.com`. And most importantly without authentication (login system)

Comment: Using a GUID as a URL parameter could be a route you look into.

Comment: I didn't understand

Comment: Just pass some kind of identifier as a header in your http request then check for it on the API

Comment: A GUID is a unique key that gets generated. So, if you want to use something instead of a login, you can generate the GUID and use that as your "key". Meaning, someone would hit the url of "www.yoursite.com/GUIDgoesHere". The guid is the key that unlocks the data. Just make sure that nobody else gets the guid that isn't suppose to see the data.

Comment: According to this post. Don't rely on custom headers. http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/09/12/securing-api-keys-in-a-client-side-javascript-app/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, every API request must go through `https`.

Then you can "secure" user-specific APIs by giving each user a unique token which must be sent at every request. 
It is as well possible to check the host or useragent of the user which requests the API and allow only specific custom useragents (depending on your needs).

Other than that: 
If you need a JSON response while the user is logged in on the same server, you can check if a given cookie or session is set and can be related to that one specific user.

If you do server to server requests for that API, you could check if the server hostname is valid and matches the one(s) who are allowed to have access.

You can as well use encryption to secure your API response (here as well: depending on your needs). If this is true, you can use a private/public key encryption similar to GPG/PGP. Of course, only the one who should have access to the API should be allowed to decrypt the response.

GUID (Globally Unique Identifier) may be an option if you don't care if anyone could find out the path to your API. GUID URLs could look like this:

`example.com/api/v1/c9a646d3-9c61-4cb7-bfcd-ee2522c8f633`

Comment: I have a site which just consume the json api without user login.

Comment: Then set a cookie for every user which is allowed to access the page. Somehow you need to know if the user is allowed or not to see the API response, even without login. Probably by checking the IP address or hostname?

Comment: This post mentions don't rely on IP Addresses: http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/09/12/securing-api-keys-in-a-client-side-javascript-app/

Comment: @AshishRawat I did mention other ways beside IP addresses. It all depends on how you want to recognize that the user is allowed to see the API response. You can check if the user recently ( < x seconds) visited your site, save that request in your database and then allow him to see the API response (based on a session which will be updated at every request for example)

Comment: that info can be passed on as the JWT's payload, no?

Comment: Sure, the JWT payload works the same way as I described